# React - load static images

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using webpack for react.js but have problem to load static images. 
In my react components I try to load images from for example mainContainer.js file. I tried with file-loader and I think that I set it all correctly but still webpack simple doesn't recognize images folder.

Here's an inline link to [Github](https://github.com/aleksandarbatin/zemun-dev/tree/image-loader).

Part from my .js component where I'm trying to load image:

```
<a href="/" className="author">
    <span className="name">Jane Doe</span><img src="./images/avatar.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

and part of webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/scripts/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        // publicPath: '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['es2015']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractPlugin.extract({
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'images/',
                            publicPath: 'images/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
                use: 'url-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractPlugin,
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
        // new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
    ]
};
```

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code instead of a link to github

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @SyedAqeel  i edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do this is by using the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy all of my static images into the build folder. Then in my components I can reference them as if they exist at the root level:

```
const copy = new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: ROOT + '/images', to: 'images' }
]);
```

In your component:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" />
```